# why android FragmentManger class designed to use transaction?

Tags: android, fragmentmanager

In my opinion, the FragmentManager is used for 2 purpose, one is store the fragments and the other is to get the back stack of them. Can we just use one array, and we can still get the same function, why the Android is designed to use such complex solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest use case of Fragment Transaction is that multiple Fragments can be added/removed/replaced in a single transaction, all done together if they are part of one transaction. IF you add it to a back stack, then all of these operations will be reversed, the removed Fragment will be added again, and the added one will be removed. If we were doing it for a single fragment, in that case Transactions wouldn't be necessary but since multiple fragments could be hosted in an Activity, hence Fragment Transactions are necessary.